# Ubuntu 20.04 not connecting to Ethernet device

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ethernet, adapter

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.5 on my MacbookPro (Early 2015) to work on my University internship project, and I am trying to connect a RedPitaya FPGA Board as per the [instructions](https://redpitaya.com/rtd-iframe/?iframe=https://redpitaya.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickStart/first.html).

It is supposed to work simply by plugging in and then going to the address of the device rp-xxxxxx.local/ . I am using a [Benfei USB Ethernet adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KWC7D78) whose drivers I downloaded from their official [website](https://www.think-benfei.com/p_driver.html). It seems the ethernet driver 'r8152' is already supposed to be preinstalled with Ubuntu 20.04 but since my device was stuck on 'connecting' and never actually connected I downloaded the drivers from the website.

It was in a .tar file and I installed it as per the following :

Extracting the files

```
tar -xf r8152.53.56-2.14.0.tar
```

I changed the directory this is the list of files that were extracted :

```
50-usb-realtek-net.rules  compatibility.h  Makefile  r8152.c  ReadMe.txt
```

In the above directory I ran the command

```
make
```

After that the directory had the following files :

```
50-usb-realtek-net.rules  Makefile       Module.symvers  r8152.ko   r8152.mod.c  r8152.o
compatibility.h           modules.order  r8152.c         r8152.mod  r8152.mod.o  ReadMe.txt
```

Then I finally ran the command

```
make install
```

But i got following error

```
rmmod r8152
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:799 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'r8152': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module r8152: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:36: install] Error 1
```

Then i tried to do the following

```
sudo make install
```

And this was the result

```
rmmod r8152
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-139-generic/build M=/home/sourabh/Downloads/r8152-2.14.0 INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/net/usb modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-139-generic'
  INSTALL /home/sourabh/Downloads/r8152-2.14.0/r8152.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  5.4.0-139-generic
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-139-generic'
modprobe r8152
```

And I also executed the following because they were recommended in the ReadMe.txt file

```
sudo depmod -a
```

and

```
update-initramfs -u
```

with output

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-139-generic
```

After all this, it seemed that the installation was done correctly but still every time I try to connect the device, it gets detected, it has the status 'connecting' for a while and then it fails to connect.

I am sure that there is no fault with the device because it connects and works fine with on MacOS. I request you to please help fix this.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, please help me fix this so I can connect to the device.

Following up with some more information :

I ran the following command

```
sudo nmcli connection show
```

which gave the following output

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE  >
Wired connection 1  37aafbb6-84cd-4ffc-a034-4a31be5f2173  ethern>
Sharies             17791b79-91f9-4691-908f-9cb2ade1685f  wifi  >
```

and then I ran the command

```
sudo nmcli connection up "Wired connection 1"
```

which gave error

```
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=37aafbb6-84cd-4ffc-a034-4a31be5f2173 + NM_DEVICE=enx3c18a0d4d71a' to get more details.
```

Comment: Why don't you install 22.04. It should work there without any actions.

Comment: I have tried it with 22.04 and on 18.04, OS i think version is not issue here.

Comment: This device is natively supported by 22.04.2 and 22.10.

Comment: Okay, I will upgrade and try. Will update here after that.

Comment: You better create a 20.04.2 LiveUSB and test from there instead of upgrading.

Comment: Please confirm which version I should try 22.04.2 OR 22.10 OR 20.04.2 ?

Comment: You need 22.04.2

Comment: I tried connecting with live-usb running 22.04.2 and still got the same issue. I also updated the question with what else I tried, maybe it would provide more info.